# What does Map's size() method return?

Tags: java, dictionary, size

I have a map declared as follows -

```
Map<Date, Long[]> myMap = new TreeMap<Date, Long[]>();
```

I put some key-value pairs in that map, check the size as follows -

```
myMap.size(); //returns 29

myMap.values().size(); //returns 31
```

All the dates (keys) are distinct.

Aren't those two supposed to return same values?

Comment: Are there any Date objects pointing to the same array of Longs?

Comment: @seand: Can to keys point to same value?

Comment: Yes.  You can have k0 -> v0 and k1 -> v0.  However I'm not sure that the map would really care about that.  I was a little surprised to see the key count and value count differ.

Comment: Two `Date` keys can be associated with the same `Long[]` value, but this shouldn't cause the behaviour you describe (if it had any effect at all, it would have to be the other way around).

Comment: I think we'd all be better off if you showed us a small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org). We'd be much better able to help you if we could reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not quite an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Again, please read the link -- but only if you want our help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given that the collection returned by TreeMap's values() method (in JDK 6, at least) has a size as follows:

```
public int size() {
    return TreeMap.this.size();
}
```

I'd say you have something adding new entries to the map between your two `size()` calls. To be clear, `map.values().size()` delegates to `map.size()`. Therefore there's no way they can return two different values for the same map with the same contents.

Comment: +1 I thought of the same thing but assumed the poster would have ruled that out already.  Also another thread could be mucking with the hashtable.

Comment: @seand: I assume it's another thread, and I almost wrote that but generalized to just "something" because you never know...